# I can't apply the dark theme without showing the light theme first in a web app made with pure html, css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes

how are you?, I have a web app and I made a dark and light theme by integrating and modifying examples from other sources, I can currently can save the current applied theme in local storage to have the theme applied when I change between pages in my app, the problem that I have is when I change between pages, if the current theme is the dark one allways the light theme is displayed firts and inmediatly the dark theme is applied.

Initially I had the html document like this

```
<html>
     <body class="tema-claro">
     ..........
     <div class="salir">
        button onclick="salir()">Salir</button>
    </body
    <script src=app.js type="text/javascript></script>
</html>
```

the javascript is the following

```
"use strict";
Aplica_Estado_Inicial();

function Cambia_Tema() {
    let tTema;
    const cambiador = document.querySelector('.tema-visual');
    document.body.classList.toggle('tema-claro');
    document.body.classList.toggle('tema-oscuro');
    document.body.style.transition = "1s ease"; //indicado por openAi
    localStorage.setItem("tema", document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className);
    const className = document.body.className;
    if(className == 'tema-claro') {
        tTema = 'Oscuro';
    }
    else if(className == 'tema-oscuro') {
        tTema = 'Claro';
    }
    document.getElementById("temVis").innerHTML = tTema;
    localStorage.setItem("textoTema", tTema);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("textoTema"));
}

function Salir() {
.
.
.
}

function Aplica_Estado_Inicial() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("primeraCarga") === undefined) {
        localStorage.setItem("primeraCarga", true);
        document.body.className = "tema-claro";
        document.getElementById("temVis") = Oscuro;
    }
    if(!(localStorage.tema === undefined)) {
        document.body.className = localStorage.getItem("tema");
        document.getElementById("temVis").innerHTML = 
        localStorage.getItem("textoTema");
    }
}
```

the function `function Cambia_Tema()` is the function that changes the theme when I press a button, the function `Aplica_Tema_Inicial()` is the one that applies the actual theme to the newly loaded page but every time a new page of the app is loaded the light theme is loaded.

Trying to solve the problem I modified the Aplica_Estado_Inicial() to this way

```
function Aplica_Estado_Inicial() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("primeraCarga") === undefined) {
        localStorage.setItem("primeraCarga", true);
        document.body.className = "tema-claro";
        document.getElementById("temVis") = Oscuro;
    }
    else if(localStorage.getItem("primeraCarga") == true) {
        document.body.className = localStorage.getItem("tema");
        document.getElementById("temVis") = localStorage.getItem("textoTema");
    }
    if(!(localStorage.tema === undefined)) {
        document.body.className = localStorage.getItem("tema");
        document.getElementById("temVis").innerHTML = 
        localStorage.getItem("textoTema");
    }
}
```

to add a flag for the app to remember not to apply whatever initial on load theme that the app could have but it didn't help

and the html document to this way

```
<body onload="Aplica_Tema_Inicial()">
.
.
.
</body>
```

but this didn't work

my themes are in the following order in the CSS file

```
.tema-oscuro {
    --body-color: #161719;
    --grad-uno-color: #4d4d51;
    --grad-dos-color: #000101;
    --primary-color-light: #f6f5ff;
}

.tema-claro {
    --body-color: #e6e6d9;
    --grad-uno-color: #bbbbbb;
    --grad-dos-color: #4d4d51;
    --primary-color-light: #1e2027; 
}
```

So, if anyone can help me with this I'll be very grateful.

UPDATE 11/01, 3:10 p.m

Apparently I could solve the problem by changing several things in my code, first in the javascript file I changed both Aplica_Estado_Inicial() and Cmabia_Tema() for variables with event listeners looking for clicks on both buttons, then I stop calling Aplica_Estado_Inicial() every time the javascript file is loaded on each page of my app.

In the html document I erased all the onclick events and gave an id to the body and all the buttons to relate them with the event listeners mentioned above, finally just at the following line of the oppening `body` tag I added a `script` tag and inside that tag I included a simple if that checks if a property called "tema" is not 'null', this property is the one that stores the actual theme being applied; if the condition is met then the theme is assigned to the class of the body.

Those changes makes all the pages to load without apply the light theme first. See the code bellow

html document:

```
<body class="tema-claro">
    <script>
        if(!(localStorage.getItem("tema") == null)) {
            document.body.classList = localStorage.tema;
        }
    </script>
    ....
    <div>
    .....
    </div>
    <div class="salir">
        <button id="bloquearSistema">Salir</button>
    </div>
</body
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<noscript>Debe habilitar Javascript para ver el sitio completo</noscript>
```

of course all of that wrapped into the  tag

the javascript file like follows

```
    "use strict";

    var estados = document.getElementById("temVis");
    estados.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let tTema;
    const cambiador = document.querySelector('.tema-visual');
    document.body.classList.toggle('tema-claro');
    document.body.classList.toggle('tema-oscuro');
    document.body.style.transition = "1s ease"; //indicado por openAi
    localStorage.setItem("tema", document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className);
    const className = document.body.className;
    if(className == 'tema-claro') {
        tTema = 'Oscuro';
    }
    else if(className == 'tema-oscuro') {
        tTema = 'Claro';
    }
    document.getElementById("temVis").innerHTML = tTema;
    localStorage.setItem("textoTema", tTema);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("textoTema"));
});

var bloqueado = document.getElementById("bloquearSistema");
bloqueado.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var sHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
    sHTTP.open("GET", "no-permitido", true);
    sHTTP.send();
    setTimeout(function(){window.open("autenticar.html", "_self");}, 1000);    
});
```

Comment: Hey Vran, the issue might be that your JavaScript is not being executed immediately can you show us your script tag? Are you importing a separate JavaScript file? Is your script inside your head? Is your script deferred?

Comment: Hey @Cookie_Wookie_7, I've updated the code for the html document, there you can see how is declared the javascript file, it is declared after the closing tag for the body and not in the head, I made the declaration after the body becuause when I called the function at the button "salir" with the onclick attribute to call the function salir(), then the page inspector was trhowing an error if the javascript file is defined in the head because the the html button who calls salir() doesn't know who is the button.

Comment: @Cookie_Wookie_7 apparently the problem is solved because right now the dark theme is being loaded well enough. The original post is updated in how I did

Comment: Ok glad you found something that worked. for the benefit of people in the future you typically want to set theme CSS in the HTML head. you might find this project interesting where I do something somewhat similar for changing the board color. https://github.com/nstringham/othello-web-app

Comment: I also found that use the onclick() event as an attibute of the any html tag y considered bad practice, like shown in this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem by changing several things in my code, first in the javascript file I changed both Aplica_Estado_Inicial() and Cmabia_Tema() for variables with event listeners looking for clicks on both buttons, then I stop calling Aplica_Estado_Inicial() every time the javascript file is loaded on each page of my app.

In the html document I erased all the onclick events and gave an id to the body and all the buttons to relate them with the event listeners mentioned above, finally just at the following line of the oppening body tag I added a script tag and inside that tag I included a simple if that checks if a property called "tema" is not 'null', this property is the one that stores the actual theme being applied; if the condition is met then the theme is assigned to the class of the body.

Those changes makes all the pages to load without apply the light theme first. See the code bellow

html document:

```
<body class="tema-claro">
    <script>
        if(!(localStorage.getItem("tema") == null)) {
            document.body.classList = localStorage.tema;
        }
    </script>
    ....
    <div>
    .....
    </div>
    <div class="salir">
        <button id="bloquearSistema">Salir</button>
    </div>
</body
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<noscript>Debe habilitar Javascript para ver el sitio completo</noscript>
```

of course all of that wrapped into the tag `<html>`

the javascript file like follows

```
"use strict";

var estados = document.getElementById("temVis");
estados.addEventListener("click", function() {
let tTema;
const cambiador = document.querySelector('.tema-visual');
document.body.classList.toggle('tema-claro');
document.body.classList.toggle('tema-oscuro');
document.body.style.transition = "1s ease"; //indicado por openAi
localStorage.setItem("tema", document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className);
const className = document.body.className;
if(className == 'tema-claro') {
    tTema = 'Oscuro';
}
else if(className == 'tema-oscuro') {
    tTema = 'Claro';
}
document.getElementById("temVis").innerHTML = tTema;
localStorage.setItem("textoTema", tTema);
console.log(localStorage.getItem("textoTema"));
});

var bloqueado = document.getElementById("bloquearSistema");
bloqueado.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var sHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
    sHTTP.open("GET", "no-permitido", true);
    sHTTP.send();
    setTimeout(function(){window.open("autenticar.html", "_self");}, 1000);    
});
```